# How can I encode string variable to keccak in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keccak

I want encode block_string variable to keccak.

This is my current function. In this code I use sha256 (hashlib library) for encode block_string value but I want to use keccak instead of sha256:

```
def hash(block):
        block_string = json.dumps(block, sort_keys=True).encode()
        return hashlib.sha256(block_string).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. "didn't work" is a very vague description of a problem. Perhaps you would like to [edit] your question and explain better.

Comment: Also `print keccak_hash.hexdigest()` would give a syntax error in Python 3. Unless that is the problem you are asking about, this does not seem to be a good code example to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be a byte literal. Try:
`a = b'some date'`

Alternatively you could do `a=a.encode('UTF-8')` to achieve the same purpose.

Full corrected code:

```
from Crypto.Hash import keccak
a = b'some date'
# Alternatively
# a = 'some date'
# a = a.encode('UTF-8')
keccak_hash = keccak.new(digest_bits=512)
keccak_hash.update(a)
print (keccak_hash.hexdigest())
```

Comment: but i want use variable

Comment: this is a variable

Comment: the rest of the code stays the same, just add the character b before the string

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto' even after insalling Crypto